# Derivation of the product of Gaussian functions

Tags: gaussian

I am trying to derive the form of the product of two Gaussian functions of the form $\chi = e^{-\alpha|r - A|^2}$, where $\alpha$ is a positive constant and $A$ is a 3D vector. These are used in computational chemistry to represent the orbitals, so I know what the result should be, but I don't quite get that result and can't find any detailed proof of this.

Let $\chi_P$ be the product of two Gaussian functions of that form:
$$
\chi_p = e^{-\alpha_a|r - A|^2}e^{-\alpha_b|r - B|^2}
= e^{-\alpha_a(r² -2Ar + A²) -\alpha_b(r² -2Br + B²)}
$$
Let us consider only the exponent ($\kappa$) for now.
$$
\kappa = -((\alpha_a + \alpha_b)r² - 2*(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)r + ( \alpha_aA² + \alpha_bB²))
$$
By completing the square, one arrives at:
$$
 \kappa = -\left(r² - 2\frac{(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)r}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b} + \frac{(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)²}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)² } - \frac{(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)²}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)² }  + \frac{\alpha_aA² +\alpha_bB²}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)
 = -\left(\left(r - \frac{A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)^2 - \frac{(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)²}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)² } + \frac{\alpha_aA² +\alpha_bB²}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)
= -\left(\left(r - \frac{A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)^2 + \frac{(\alpha_a\alpha_b)*(A-B)^2}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)^2}\right)
$$
Accordingly, $\chi_P$ is:
$$
e^{-\left(r - \frac{A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)^2}*e^{-\frac{(\alpha_a\alpha_b)*(A-B)^2}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)^2}}
$$

But actually, the result [should be](https://content.wolfram.com/uploads/sites/19/2012/02/Ho.pdf):
$$
e^{-(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)\left(r - \frac{A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)^2}*e^{-\frac{(\alpha_a\alpha_b)*(A-B)^2}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}}
$$

I don't quite see how to get this form or what mistake I made.

Comment: Ask yourself where you lost the $(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)r²$ term

Comment: Oh I see! Care to make an official answer or should I answer it myself?

Comment: It's all yours...

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was on the third line.

$$
\kappa = -\left(r^2 - 2\frac{(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)r}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b} + \frac{(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)^2}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)^2 }\right)
$$
Should instead be
$$
\kappa = -(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)\left(r^2 - 2\frac{(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)r}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b} + \frac{(A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b)^2}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)^2 }\right)
$$

Following the same steps, we arrive at:
$$
\kappa = -(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)\left(\left(r - \frac{A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)^2 + \frac{(\alpha_a\alpha_b)*(A-B)^2}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)^2}\right)
$$

And thus:
$$
\chi_P = e^{-(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)\left(r - \frac{A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)^2}*e^{-(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)\frac{(\alpha_a\alpha_b)*(A-B)^2}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)^2}} = e^{-(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)\left(r - \frac{A\alpha_a + B\alpha_b}{\alpha_a + \alpha_b}\right)^2}*e^{-\frac{(\alpha_a\alpha_b)*(A-B)^2}{(\alpha_a + \alpha_b)}}
$$